# Avoiding "NSArray was mutated while being enumerated"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, collections, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` that stores mousejoints for a Box2d physics simulation. When using more than one finger to play I'll get exceptions stating

> NSArray was mutated while being enumerated

I know this is because I'm deleting objects from the array while also enumerating through it, invalidating the enum.

What I want to know is what is the best strategy to solve this going forward? I've seen a few solutions online: `@synchronized`, copying the array before enumerating or putting the touch joint into a garbage array for later deletion (which I'm not sure would work, because I need to remove the mousejoint from the array straight after removing it from the world).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can always iterate without an enumerator.
Which means a regular **for** loop, and when you remove an object:- decrement the index variable and **continue;**.
if you are caching the array's count before entering the for-loop, then make sure you decrement that too when removing an object.

Anyway, I do not see why an array with objects for later removal would be a problem. I do not know the exact situation which you are having and the technologies involved, but theoretically there should not be a problem.
Because in most cases when using this method you can just do nothing in the first enumeration, and do the real work when enumerating the removal array.
And if you have a situation where in the first enumeration you are checking something *again* against the same array and you need to know that the objects are not there anymore, you can just add a check to see if they are in the removal array.

Anyway, hope I helped.
Good luck!

Comment: "Anyway, hope I helped"; Certainly helped me, A LOT! Thank you!

Comment: This does not work for the same problem but with NSMutableSet rather than arrays. Do you have a suggestion for that scenario?

Comment: @VictorEngel yes, create a separate set with all the item you wish to remove, then use "minusSet" on the original set (or a mutableCopy of it) with the second set as the argument. :)

Comment: I got this error when use block enumerate method in iOS6.

Answer (score 38):

You can do something like this:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [yourArray copy];
for(id obj in tempArray) {
    //It's safe to remove objects from yourArray here.
}
[tempArray release];
```

Comment: This is not true. I still get a mutated while being enumerated exception.

Comment: Should `tempArray` instead be initialized like `NSArray *tempArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:yourArray]`? It seems like this snippet of code wouldn't do what the OP intended

Comment: @TimArnold I'm pretty sure that would give the same result.

Comment: @Brendt please, show your snippet of code. This answer is seems correct for me. Because we work with different container and it stores all objects from yourArray retained.

Comment: Use `for (int = 0; i < yourArray.count; i++) { /* It's safe to remove objects from yourArray here.*/ } `, this will not use the enumerator of array.

Answer (score 38):

The simplest way is to enumerate **backwards** through the array which means the next index won't be affected when you remove an object.

```
for (NSObject *object in [myMutableArray reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    // it is safe to test and remove the current object      
    if (AddTestHere) {
        [myMutableArray removeObject: object];
    }
}
```

Comment: simplest & efficient answer

Comment: This is not correct. From [the reverseObjectEnumerator documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415734-reverseobjectenumerator): "When you use this method with mutable subclasses of NSArray, you must not modify the array during enumeration."

Comment: That's a general warning but obviously it is more subtle than that. Modifying the NSMutableArray by inserting or deleting elements EARLIER than the current index will create problems but that isn't what is being done here. Trust me I've been using this technique for 6+ years without a single issue. It works just fine.

Comment: Just because it "works fine" does not mean it's correct. You can call private API it too will "work fine" until Apple decides to change it, and then you will crash. You're relying on an internal implementation detail and explicitly doing what the documentation tells you not to do. Use one of the supported ways of doing this, please.

Comment: Don't be silly. What "internal implementation detail" am I relying on?

Answer (score 6):

Lock (@synchronized) operation is much faster then copying entire array over and over again. Of course this depends on how many elements the array has, and how often is it executed.
Imagine you have 10 threads executing this method simultaneously:

```
- (void)Callback
{
  [m_mutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
  //m_mutableArray is instance of NSMutableArray declared somewhere else

  NSArray* tmpArray = [m_mutableArray copy];
  NSInteger sum = 0;
  for (NSNumber* num in tmpArray)
      sum += [num intValue];

  //Do whatever with sum
}
```

It is copying n+1 objects each time. You can use lock here, but what if there is 100k elements to iterate? Array will be locked until iteration is completed, and other threads will have to wait until lock is released. I think copying object here is more effective, but it also depends on how big that object are and what are you doing in iteration. Lock should be always keept for the shortest period of time. So I would use lock for something like this.

```
- (void)Callback
{
  NSInteger sum = 0;
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if(m_mutableArray.count == 5)
      [m_mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:4];
    [m_mutableArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] atIndex:0];

    for (NSNumber* num in tmpArray)
      sum += [num intValue];
  }
  //Do whatever with sum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(MyObject *obj in objQueue)
{
//[objQueue removeObject:someof];//NEVER removeObject in a for-in loop
    [self dosomeopearitions];
}

//instead of remove outside of the loop
[objQueue removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

All the above did not work for me, but this did:

```
 while ([myArray count] > 0) 
 {
      [<your delete method call>:[myArray objectAtIndex:0]];
 }
```

Note: this will delete it all. If you need to pick which items need to be deleted, then this will not work.

Comment: To empty an array you don't need to delete the objects one by one. You can just say  

myArray = [NSMutableArray init];

Mutating isn't just about deleting, it also includes modifying the objects, which is usually what you want to do. In either case, the right way to "enumerate and mutate" an array is to create a copy of your array first and use that copy to enumerate the objects while you mutate the original array as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Using a for loop instead of enumerating is ok. But once you start deleting array elements, be careful if you're using threads. It's not enough to just decrement the counter as you may be deleting the wrong things.
One of the correct ways is to create a copy of the array, iterate the copy and delete from the original.

edc1591 is the correct method.

[Brendt: need to delete from the original while iterating through the copy]

Comment: thanks for the hint to delete from the original while iterating the copy, it wasnt clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the solution is to enumerate the copy and mutate the original, as edc1591 correctly mentioned. I've tried the code and I'm not getting the error anymore. If you're still getting the error, it means you are still mutating the copy (instead of the original) inside the for loop.

```
NSArray *copyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:originalArray];

for (id obj in copyArray) { 
    // tweak obj as you will 
    [originalArray setObject:obj forKey:@"kWhateverKey"];
}
```

Comment: `setObject:forKey` is a method of **dictionaries, not arrays** (also, it must be the **mutable** version). Otherwise, the method is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you deleted or added objects to your mutableAray while enumerating it.
In my situation error appeared in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this error and in my case it was because of the multi-threaded situation. One thread was enumerating an array while another thread removed objects from the same array at the same time. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray * founded = [NSMutableArray new];
for (XYZ * item in searchableArray) {
    if (item.xValue == 1) {
        [founded addObject:item];
    }
}
  //  NSSet * set = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:founded];
  //  [searchableArray removeItems:set];
```

Hint: in my case, the searchableArray is part of managed object