# nsmutablearray meet NSGenericException 'Collection was mutated while being enumerated'

Tags: ios, exception, nsmutablearray

I met the exception called 'Collection was mutated while being enumerated' yesterday and saw some solutions.I've got another idea.If I set an argument called 'lock' and each time I enumerate I lock it then unlock it after enumeration.Every time I'll operate it,like enumerating or add object, I lock it first then unlock it after the operation.
Could someone tell me if it will work?

Comment: I asked a similar question, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10157745/459116

Comment: I just want to know if this solution will work:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it.One of the problem is about thread safety.Use

```
    @synchronized (yourobject)
    {
    //do something with your object
    }
```

that will work.It means that it'll lock 'yourobject' so that other thread can't modify it.Then unlock it after the '}'

The other is some code about deleting objects in array.If you delete instantly,you'll meet the exception called 'Collection was mutated while being enumerated'.Create a temp array to contain objects you want to delete,then delete them all after the for loop.

```
 NSMutableArray *toDestroy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_contactor.count];
    for(Man *sprite in self.contactor)
    {
        if (sprite.hp<=0 && sprite.stat == stat_attack)
        {
            [sprite stopAllActions];
            [sprite animDead];
            [toDestroy addObject:sprite];
        }
    }
    [self.contactor removeObjectsInArray:toDestroy];
```

instead of

```
for(Man *sprite in self.contactor)
{
    if (sprite.hp<=0 && sprite.stat == stat_attack)
    {
        [sprite stopAllActions];
        [sprite animDead];
        [self.contactor removeObject:sprite];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just copy it. If it is an array do something like this:

```
NSArray *arrayToEnumerate = [myMutableArray copy];
```

Now enumerate and you won't have to worry about the non-mutable array being changed out under you.

Comment: I will change some variable in objects.Is that change to regular objects?

Comment: I don't understand what you just asked. Copying like this will only prevent the array from being modified...no additions/deletions from the array while you are enumerating. The individual objects can still be modified as you (presumably) only have pointers to them inside the array, but this shouldn't matter. If an object can be set to a value that will cause a problem during the enumeration you will just need to add an error check of some sort inside the enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change array while you're enumerating it. As a workaround you should accumulate new objects in temporary array and add them after enumeration:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [yourArray copy];

for(id obj in tempArray) {
    //It's safe to remove objects from yourArray here.

}
[tempArray release];
```