# Objective-C: Recursive method that changes property of self

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, nsmutablearray, enumeration

I have a recursive method that changes a property of self (the object on which the method is defined).

**I get the error:**

> ...uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x755f670> was mutated while being enumerated...'

I read about this error, but I'm not sure how to apply a solution to my problem.  Recursion is crucial to the solution, as is updating this particular property.  I'm very new to Objective-C, so perhaps I'm missing something or designing this solution poorly.

- `currentPlayer` is the property
- `recursiveMethod` is, obviously, the recursive method that's producing the error

This recursive method is called from within a `for in` loop.

```
    - (void) recursiveMethod:(id <Team>)team atIndex:(int *)i withPlayer:(id <Player>) {
        [self.currentPlayer replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:nextPlayer];
        if // some conditional that's unimportant to this question 
        {
            // grab another team
            // grab another index
            // grab another player
            [self recursiveMethod:nextTeam atIndex:i withPlayer:nextPlayer];
         }
    }
```

A lot of the details are unimportant.  I stripped it down; really it's just a recursive method that will update a property (in this case an array) of the object on which the method is defined.

Comment: Wow. Look what I found googling _the exact error message_ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157381/nsarray-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated

Comment: The answer GuillaumeA has pointed out says you can avoid the error by iterating yourself. However in the code sample you show that is exactly what you are doing - a recursive modification of the array. So the you must have an *enumeration* (e.g. a `for in`) within which you are calling `recursiveMethod`.

Answer (score 2):

Just **read** the exception message:

> NSArrayM [...] was mutated while being enumerated.

You can't do that.

Comment: @codework If you really need to modify the array, then `mutableCopy` it and set it after the enumeration has finished, this way it won't crash (and it will make sense :)

Comment: Yes, CRD, you are correct. My mistake for failing to include that in my original code sample. It's a recursive function called from within a `for in` loop.