# Xcode MultipleCellSelection Selection names

Tags: ios, iphone, multipleselection

I have a tableview. I want to create string from selected cell names. For example My Cell names : Row No 1 - Row No 2 - Row No 3 - Row No 4 - Row No 5. When selected Row No 1 - Row No 2 - Row No 5 mystring value = Selected Items Row No 1 , Row No 2 , Row No 5. When i deselect Row No 1 mystring value = Selected items Row No 2 , Row No 5 or Row No 5 , Row No 2. It does not matter. 
Is it possible? If possible how can i do? Thanks.

//EDIT 
My  code is here ;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tableData retain];

for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    NSString *rowInString= [[NSString  alloc ]initWithFormat:@"Row No %d",i];
    [tableData addObject:rowInString];
    rowInString=nil;
}



_mytable.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        NSLog(@"self.Data count: %lu", (unsigned long)[tableData count]);
    return tableData.count  ;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
}
NSString *cellValue;


cellValue=[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [_mytable setEditing: YES];


cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;



return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *selectedText = @"Selected Items";
NSArray *selectedRows = [_mytable indexPathsForSelectedRows];
NSLog(@"%lu" , (unsigned long)selectedRows.count);
}



- (void)dealloc {
[_mytable release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: @LyndseyScott how can i do this. Can you share example code. Thanks.

Comment: You have to show what you've tried to acheive what you want before people will help you.

Comment: What should text be if user selects five - two -three? Will it be five-two-three ot two-three-five

Comment: it does not matter. Just i wanna see same string.

Comment: View my answer below. It will work for multiple selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add in your tableview.

```
self.myTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //you need an array in which you can add and remove strings

   //adding the selected row string to array.
   [stringArray addObject:[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   NSString *string;
   for(NSString *str in stringArray)
   {
     string = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@",string,str];
   }
   NSLog(@"Selected Row %@"string);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //removing the selected string from array

    for(NSString *stringInArray in stringArray)
    {
      if([stringInArray isEqualToString:[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]])
      {
           [stringArray removeObject:stringInArray];
      }
    }

   NSString *string;
   for(NSString *str in stringArray)
   {
     string = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@%@",string,str];
   }
   NSLog(@"Selected Row %@"string);
}
```

Comment: @FawarMasud Thanks. Its work. I Create NSMuttableArray. But i change some lines . But when i deselect not remove string.

Comment: are you using same code? i mean you are not using "==" instead of "isEqualToString"?

Comment: Yes same codes. My didDeselect method isnt work. I Use NSLog(@"Deselect"); when i deselect cell i cant see log in log console.

Comment: Have you set cell selection style? if not, add cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray in your code. Also check the delegates of table view. Use breakpoints.

Comment: What Happened i dont know. I write all  codes again and it works. Thank You @FawadMasud.

Comment: When ı deselect not last object i have error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7fb0b0d876f0> was mutated while being enumerated. Do u have idea ?

Comment: Yes, it means that you are changing an array while it is being used somewhere else. For example you are removing an object from array and you are using array.count somewhere else. It creates confusion as the count of array has been changed. For details please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157381/nsarray-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:
Create a NSString *selectedText=@"Selected Items";
Now when you press a item in tableview, didselectitematibdexpath will be called.
Using the indexpath get the cell's name. Now compare if that text exist in the selectedText string. If it exist remove it from string

```
NSRange check = [selectedText rangeOfString:@" one"];

if (check.location != NSNotFound) {
selectedText = [selectedText   stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:check withString:@""];
}
```

else add it to string using

```
selectedText=[selectedText stringWithFormat:@" %@",cellName];
```

Here is your code(i have changed as per your requirement):

```
 NSString *selectedText = @"Selected Items";
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tableData retain];

    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    NSString *rowInString= [[NSString  alloc ]initWithFormat:@"Row No %d",i];
    [tableData addObject:rowInString];
    rowInString=nil;
}



_mytable.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        NSLog(@"self.Data count: %lu", (unsigned long)[tableData count]);
    return tableData.count  ;

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellidentifier=@"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellidentifier];
}
NSString *cellValue;


cellValue=[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [_mytable setEditing: YES];


cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;



return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSRange check = [selectedText rangeOfString:[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

if (check.location != NSNotFound) {
    selectedText = [selectedText   stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:check withString:@""];
} else {
    selectedText = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@ %@",selectedText, [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}
NSArray *selectedRows = [_mytable indexPathsForSelectedRows];
NSLog(@"%lu" , (unsigned long)selectedRows.count);
}



- (void)dealloc {
[_mytable release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: On the line rangeOfString instead of @" one" provide the celName

Comment: i try. But i couldn't. I share my code. Can you edit. Thank you.

Comment: i have updated in your code above. Please check now.

Comment: Thansk. But when i select two cell this line   NSRange check = [selectedText rangeOfString:[tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]]; says Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_1386_GPFLT)

Comment: You mean you have multiple selection?

Comment: Yes, I wanna Multiple Selection and i want to see selected cell names in one string.