# CoreData Concurrency issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am having issue while using `private managedObjectContext`for saving data in background. I am new to CoreData. I am using Parent-Child approach for `NSManagedObjectContext` but facing several issues.

**Errors arise when I tap reload button multiple times**

**Errors:**

> 1. 'NSGenericException', reason: Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x16e47100> was mutated while being enumerated
> 2. Some times : crash here `try managedObjectContext.save()`
> 3. Sometimes Key value coding Compliant error

**My ViewController class**

```
        class ViewController: UIViewController {
            var jsonObj:NSDictionary?
            var values = [AnyObject]()
            @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!
        
            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                getData()
                saveInBD()
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.saved(_:)), name: "kContextSavedNotification", object: nil)
            }
   //Loding json data from a json file
    
           func getData(){
            if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("countries", ofType: "json") {
            do {
            let data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
            
            
            do {
            jsonObj =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                
            } catch {
            jsonObj = nil;
            }
            
            
            } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            } else {
            print("Invalid filename/path.")
            }
            }
           **Notification reciever**
    
            func saved(not:NSNotification){
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if let data  = DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.getAllNews(){
                        self.values = data
                        print(data.count)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        
                    }
          
                }
                }
           
            func saveInBD(){
                if jsonObj != nil {
                    guard let nameArray = jsonObj?["data#"] as? NSArray else{return}
                    DatabaseManager.sharedInstance.addNewsInBackGround(nameArray)
                }
            }
            //UIButton for re-saving data again

            @IBAction func reloadAxn(sender: UIButton) {
                saveInBD()
            }
        
    }
    
    
    **Database Manager Class**
    
    public class DatabaseManager{
        
        static  let sharedInstance = DatabaseManager()
        
        let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
        
        private init() {
        }
        
        func addNewsInBackGround(arr:NSArray)  {
            let jsonArray = arr
            let moc = managedObjectContext
            
            let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
            privateMOC.parentContext = moc
           
                privateMOC.performBlock {
                    for jsonObject in jsonArray {
                        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Country",
                            inManagedObjectContext:privateMOC)
                        
                        let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                            insertIntoManagedObjectContext: privateMOC) as! Country
                        
                        managedObject.name = jsonObject.objectForKey("name")as? String
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    do {
                        try privateMOC.save()
                        
                        self.saveMainContext()
                        
                        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kContextSavedNotification", object: nil)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                           
        }
        
        
        
        
        
        func getAllNews()->([AnyObject]?){
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Country")
            fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
            
            do {
                let results =
                    try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
                results as? [NSDictionary]
                if results.count > 0
                {
                    return results
                }else
                {
                    return nil
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                return nil
            }
        }
        
        func saveMainContext () {
            if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157381/avoiding-nsarray-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** write in background and read in the main thread (using different MOCs like you do). And actually you're almost doing it right.

The app crashes on the `try managedObjectContext.save()` line, because `saveMainContext` is called from within the private MOC's performBlock. The easiest way to fix it is to wrap the save operation into another `performBlock`:

```
func saveMainContext () {
    managedObjectContext.performBlock {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                print("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other two errors are a little more tricky. Please, provide more info. What object is not key-value compliant for what key? It's most likely a JSON parsing issue.

The first error ("mutated while being enumerated") is actually a nasty one. The description is pretty straight forward: a collection was mutated by one thread while it was enumerated on the other. Where does it occur?
One possible reason (most likely one, I would say) is that it is indeed a Core Data multithreading issue. Despite the fact that you can use several threads, you can only use core data objects within the thread they were obtained on. If you pass them to another thread, you'll likely run into an error like this.

Look through your code and try to find a place where such situation might occur (for instance, do you access `self.values` from other classes?). Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find such place in several minutes. If you said upon which collection enumeration this error occurs, it would help).

**UPDATE:**
P.S. I just thought that the error might be related to the `saveMainContext` function. It is performed right before a call to `saved`. `saveMainContext` is performed on the background thread (in the original code, I mean), and `saved` is performed on the main thread. So after fixing `saveMainContext`, the error might go away (I'm not 100% sure, though).

Comment: should I call saveMainContext() from the private block an d use as you suggested `managedObjectContext.performBlock {}` only where it is defined.

Comment: @NA000022, yes, it should work. Another way to do is is to leave the `saveMainContext` method itself unchanged, but wrap a call to it into a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`. The first case is better to my mind, because in the second case we'd have to remember to wrap this function whenever we call it. Our goal is to ensure that we only call `managedObjectContext.save()` on the main thread. The way we do it is not that important.

Comment: It is working perfectly  but now I face another problem. If I taps reloadAction() which is used to save data in private MOC, the UI hangs for 1 sec and it increases continuously as records are growing.

Comment: @NA000022, the proper way to deal with such issues is to use Instruments / Time Profiler to find the piece of code that takes a long time to complete on the main thread while the UI hangs. But given that it started after the latest fixes, the most probable cause is actually the main MOC saving operation. Saving to disk is slow. There is a workaround. You can create another private MOC (let's call it savingMOC). `mainMOC.parentContext = savingContext`. Like so: [The Big Nerd Ranch Core Data Stack](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/introducing-the-big-nerd-ranch-core-data-stack/#nested).

Answer (score -1):

You are violating thread confinement.

You cannot write to CoreData in Background, and read in MainThread.

All operation on CoreData must be done in the same thread

Comment: How can I use same thread as the private queue runs on different Thread

Comment: create a reference `dispatch_queue_create()`, and then dispatch_async() to execute code in it

Comment: So I should create my own thread and do all the stuff on that.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I highly recommend you to not do that. You should instead perform all operations in the main tread

Comment: But I think Parent-Child context  uses its seperate thread for saving data.

Comment: @NA000022, of course you can use several threads. Give me a second.

Comment: @FreeNickname sure :)

Comment: Several thread means several context. I didn't say it was impossible, I said it is much more complicated to implement comparing to thread confinement strategy