# NSMutableArray was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, arrays, macos, cocoa

I have an array in an old objective-C app that I am using to learn more "complicated" coding. It is back from the old days of OS X and was very much broken. I have gotten it to work (mostly)! However, the app has an NSMutableArray of images, 7 in total. I use a random number generator to insert the images on the screen, some code to allow them to fall, and then, using screen bounds, when they reach "0" on the Y axis they are removed from the array.
I initially just had:

```
if( currentFrame.origin.y+currentFrame.size.height <= 0 )
        {
         [flakesArray removeObject:myItem];
```

I have read when removing objects from an array it is best practice to iterate in reverse...so I have this bit of code:

```
for (NSInteger i = myArray.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     { //added for for statement
   if( currentFrame.origin.y+currentFrame.size.height <= 0 )
        {
    [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
```

Sadly both methods result in the same mutated while enumerated error. Am I missing something obvious? 
If I add an NSLog statement I can get, I think, the index of the item that needs to be removed:

```
NSLog (@"Shazam! %ld", (long)i);
```

2017-01-07 14:39:42.086667 MyApp[45995:7500033] Shazam! 2

I have looked through a lot and tried several different methods including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157381/avoiding-nsarray-was-mutated-while-being-enumerated), which looks to be the most popular with the same error.

Thank you in advance! I will happily provide any additional information!

Adding more:
Sorry guys I am not explicitly calling NSFastEnumeration but I have this:

```
- (void) drawRectCocoa:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSEnumerator* flakesEnum = [flakesArray objectEnumerator];
```

then

```
for( i = 0; i < numberToCreate; i++ )
    {
        [self newObject:self];
    }
  while( oneFlake = [flakesEnum nextObject] )
```

It is here where:

```
 if( currentFrame.origin.y+currentFrame.size.height <= 0 )
       {
        NSLog (@"Shazam! %i", oneFlake);
 [flakesArray removeObject:oneFlake];
}
```

Thank you all. I am learning a lot from this discussion!

Comment: The error says you're using fast enumeration somewhere, but there's no fast enumeration in this question.  Are you loops nested in any other loops?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to go: (1) collect the objects to remove then remove them with [removeObjectsInArray:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray/1413942-removeobjectsinarray?language=objc).

```
NSMutableArray *removeThese = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id item in myArray) {
    if (/* item satisfies some condition for removal */) {
        [removeThese addObject:item];
    }
}

// the following (and any other method that mutates the array) must be done
// *outside of* the loop that enumerates the array
[myArray removeObjectsInArray:removeThese];
```

Alternatively, `reverseObjectEnumeration` is tolerant of removes during iteration...

```
for (id item in [myArray reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if (/* item satisfies some condition for removal */) {
        [myArray removeObject: item];
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a warning: the [Apple doc for reverseObjectEnumerator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1415734-reverseobjectenumerator?language=objc) says explicitly "When you use this method with mutable subclasses of NSArray, you must not modify the array during enumeration.".

Answer (score 3):

As per the error, you may not mutate any `NSMutableArray` (or any `NSMutable...` collection) while it is being enumerated as part of any fast enumeration loop (`for (... in ...) { ... }`).

@danh's answer works as well, but involves allocating a new array of elements. There are two simpler and more efficient ways to filter an array:

```
[array filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(id element, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *bindings) {
    // if element should stay, return YES; if it should be removed, return NO
}];
```

or

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indicesToRemove = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < array.count; i += 1) {
    if (/* array[i] should be removed */) {
        [indicesToRemove addIndex:i];
    }
}

[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indicesToRemove];
```

[`filterUsingPredicate:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray/1412085-filterusingpredicate?language=objc) will likely be slightly faster (since it uses fast enumeration itself), but depending on the specific application, [`removeObjectsAtIndexes:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray/1410154-removeobjectsatindexes?language=objc) may be more flexible.

No matter what, if you're using your array inside a fast enumeration loop, you will have to perform the modification outside of the loop. You can use `filterUsingPredicate:` to replace the loop altogether, or you can keep the loop and keep track of the indices of the elements you want to remove for later.

Comment: But there is no fast enumeration in the question.  The loop in the question is probably nested in a fast enumeration loop (maybe with method calls in between).

Comment: @NobodyNada The question mentions a "mutated while enumerated error"; to me that indicates that they're using fast enumeration somewhere and mutating this array while doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout, but please note that `indicesToRemove` is every bit an "intermediate array" also.

Comment: Right, but the fast enumeration isn't in the question.

Comment: @danh True, but index sets are implemented as range arrays; they are faster to iterate and add to, and have a smaller memory footprint. They also don't contain objects, so there is no intermediate memory management (unnecessary object retains and releases under ARC). Overall, more efficient to use in applications like this. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: @NobodyNada I don't understand your first comment, then. Your first sentence says there is no fast enumeration in the question, and your second says that they are probably using fast enumeration. Which is it? If they were not using fast enumeration, they would not be seeing an error.

Comment: They're using fast enumeration, but it's not in the question.  My guess is that they have a fast enumeration loop on the array, and the loop in the question is nested inside of this loop.

Comment: @NobodyNada Sure; we are both in agreement that there is a fast enumeration loop _somewhere_ here, implicitly or not, correct? No matter what this inner loop does, as long as the outer loop is there, they may not mutate the array, no matter what they do — fast enumeration disallows this. If they want to filter elements, they will have to either stop using fast enumeration (no matter where it is), or use one of the above methods, outside of the loop.